# Cheat Sheet for Glossaries Package

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package and always end up searching through the long documentation to find frequently used commands like `\acrshort`.

Is there a nice compact cheat sheet available? If not, I would like to propose a community wiki entry which summarizes most frequently used commands and links to the documentation (which consists of several files) for further reading.

I would like to see the following details:

- Usage for math notation
- Usage for standard glossary
- Usage for acronyms
- Most common problems for grammar (plurals, cases for other languages)

Comment: Have you seen the beginners' guide? The package comes with both a short, focused guide for getting started which covers the basics, and an in-depth user manual. It seems you are likely using the former but may prefer the latter for most cases.